# How to have Phantomjs execute a js file on Windows

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I just executed phantomjs.exe and a command line window popup. 
    How could I execute the .js files under ./examples/? If just enter the file name "version.js", I got the error message - "cannot find the variable: version".

Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Open the command window - this can be done by holding SHIFT + Right mouse click and there is a choice of Open command window here...

From the command line you can then invoke the phantomjs.exe

```
  $ path/to/phantomjs.exe path/to/version.js
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also create windows environment path variable

add **path/to/phantomjs.exe**  as environment variable with name **phantomjs**

then From the command line you can then invoke the phantomjs

```
$ phantomjs path/to/version.js
```

Comment: It will not work adding the new environment variable `phantomjs`. You have to include `path/to/phantomjs.exe` into the `PATH` variable.

Answer (score 1):

A better answer (I think) is : Add the path to the folder containing phantomjs.exe, to the PATH environment variable :) on Windows.