# How to open a .js file with phantomjs?

Tags: phantomjs

I was trying to install XSS Validator for Burpsuite and I need to use phantomjs for that however I can't open the xss.js file. Sadly I have very little code knowledge. I tried following other tutorials but still coulding figure it out.

I'm using the executable phantomjs.exe version. Am I supposed to drag the xss.js file into the phantomjs command line or copy the directory of it and enter?

Comment: You can *run* JavaScript scripts in PhantomJS and you can *open* webpages that contain JavaScript scripts. What exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
phantomjs --help
Usage:
   phantomjs [switchs] [options] [script] [argument [argument [...]]]
```

So you need to run it as

```
/path/to/phantomjs.exe path/to/xss.js
```

Also found a detailed discussion:
[How to have Phantomjs execute a js file on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551218/how-to-have-phantomjs-execute-a-js-file-on-windows)